# How to set zapier cli authentication?

Tags: node.js, zapier

I am trying to build an app using zapier cli.
I am having a problem with authorizing the request .
I am using an api key and a client id.
When I try to use the same credentials in the UI
Its working perfect , however in the cli it gives an error code 403.

I have listed the code below . What could be the issue ?

```
//test 
"use strict";

const should = require("should");

const zapier = require("zapier-platform-core");

const App = require("../index");
const appTester = zapier.createAppTester(App);

describe("custom authentication authentication", () => {
  // Put your test TEST_USERNAME and TEST_PASSWORD in a .env file.
  // The inject method will load them and make them available to use in your
  // tests.
  zapier.tools.env.inject();

  it("should authenticate", (done) => {
    const bundle = {
      authData: {
        api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
        client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      },
    };

    appTester(App.authentication, bundle)
      .then((response) => {
        should.exist(response);
        done();
      })
      .catch(done);
  });
});


//authentication.js

"use strict";

const currentDate = new Date();
const year = currentDate.getFullYear();
const month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
const day = currentDate.getDate();

const authentication = (z, bundle) => {
  const options = {
    url: "url",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      ContentType: "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
      "x-api-key": bundle.authData["api_key"],
      client_id: bundle.authData["client_id"],
    },
    params: {
      year: year,
      month: month,
      day: day,
      page_size: "1000",
    },
  };

  return z.request(options).then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
  });
};

module.exports = authentication;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have values in a `.env` file at the application root? You can also double check that `console.log(process.env.API_KEY)` prints a value when the test is running.

---

As an aside, you can use the `zapier convert` CLI command to copy your integration from the UI to the CLI without having to re-write it. If it works in the UI, it'll work in the CLI too.